# Is there any package without awt, swing for finding string length in java

Tags: java

Hi am new to java is there any other way to find string length pixel without using awt and swing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The length depends on how the `String` is rendered, so obviously only libraries that know how to render a String will be able to tell how big it would be.

It's as if I asked you to tell me the required dimensions if I wrote my username on paper.

Comment: Ok Thanq why am asking this one because am using svg when am draw graph its very slow performance because awt package

Comment: I doubt it's AWT's fault. You should instead show the code you're using to draw the SVG, it probably has performance problems.